# Pig Latin - Using Include on Array range

Tags: ruby

Working on a pig latin translator. Is there a better way/less redundant to write the below:

```
consonants.include?(word[0]) && consonants.include?(word[1]) && consonants.include?(word[2])

word[3..-1] + word[0..2] + 'ay'
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving existing code, not fixing broken code, and should be on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`all?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F).

```
word[0..2].all? { |c| consonants.include?(c) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
word[0..2].chars.all?(&consonants.method(:include?))
```